# What are map files generated during compilation

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, visual-c++-6

What info map file contain generated during compilation of project and how i enable /map option in **makefile**.

**Language :** c++

**compiler :** vc6

Comment: See this closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755783/whats-the-use-of-map-files-the-linker-produces

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx is a decent introduction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/map-generate-mapfile) for the /MAP linker option:

> A mapfile is a text file that contains
> the following information about the
> program being linked:
>
> - The module name, which is the base name of the file
> - The timestamp from the program file header (not from the file system)
> - A list of groups in the program, with each group's start address (as
>   section:offset), length, group name,
>   and class
> - A list of public symbols, with each address (as section:offset), symbol
>   name, flat address, and .obj file
>   where the symbol is defined
> - The entry point (as section:offset)