# Position of functions in executable

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker

Is there a requirement in the C standard that functions in the compiled (and linked) binary will appear in the ordered they are written in the C file?

> Please assume that in the example below the compiler did not remove / inline any function, and they all exist in the binary. the question is not about what the compiler might do with empty function, but about the order of the functions.

For example, if I compile example.c:

```
void bar() {  }
void foo() {  bar();  }
int main() {   foo();  }
```

Can I be sure that `foo` will come after `bar` in the output file?

Comment: I don't think there's _anything_ in the C standard about object file layout (or even about object files). Why would that be an interesting guarantee even if there was?

Comment: @Mat - I was discussing with someone regarding the option of finding the size of a function (approx.) by substracting its pointer from the pointer of the next function. It comes handy in some cases.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet That's a reasonable use case, but it's something that should be done using the platform's ABI library (libelf, libmacho, etc.). If an implementation properly documents these details, that itself is (should be?) enough to perform such a calculation properly.

Comment: The compiler can change your code (in-memory) to `int main() { }` and compile this instead. Note that there is no function `foo()` or `bar()` now :)

Comment: @H2CO3 - thanks, I did not mention a specific format or tool chain because the platforms that I am interested in are not standard and may  not have such libraries, in fact, since some of them are embedded, they may not have available libraries at all, as the whole image is a single binary file.

Comment: @pmg - sure, I just wanted to supply a short example of what I am talking about. I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Oh, I see. (Just curious: any chance the implementation is opensource and you can extract the necessary parts from the binutils in order to make your calculations?)

Comment: @pmg, while simplifying `main` to nothing is completely legitimate, the compiler will not delete the symbols because they are exported with visible linkage. This means they could theoretically be called even without any code path leading to them (for instance with `dlsym`).

Comment: @H2CO3 - most of the times I will be able to do that, but not always, and unfortunatly, the implementation is usually not open source at all.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet, your problem sounds like an X-Y problem. Shouldn't your question rather be "how can I find the approximate size a function occupies in memory"?

Comment: Any sophisticated compiler can do code motion.  This means it may move parts of the function body outside of the "intuitively obvious" way of generating the code in a contiguous region of code space.  (One reason to do this is to place code blocks in cache lines that do not conflict; in this case, your function is scattered across cache lines).  Bottom line: you don't have any guarantee that the function has dense range of addresses that it occupies, unless your compiler provides such a guarantee.

Comment: As a specific experience, older Microsoft C compilers place functions in source code order.  The MS 2010 C compiler rearranges function order.  It has a way of optionally specifying function order as a linker command, and it happens to place code contiguously. [I happened to need something pretty close to what you need. In this case, I got what you want :-}  I worry about what happens when I go to MS 2012.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't such a requirement in the C standard. In terms of compilation and linkage, only particular properties of functions, such as extern or static linkage, etc. are mentioned explicitly, but even these are described in a mostly implementation-independent manner. There's no clause (as far as I know) in any of the standard documents so far that imposes expectations about the order of symbols in an executable.

Comment: There is not even a guarantee that a function will occupy continuous set of addresses (newer GCC versions may split a function into a "hot" and "cold" regions, MSVC compilers also do that). See also http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2011-09/msg01440.html

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes, that's correct, just like the storage of the old `std::string` in C++03.

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule for this in the language. Typically, they do come in the order you expect from looking at the code, but there is nothing saying the compiler can't build a stack of functions, and output them in the completely opposite order - certainly, a function that isn't called can be deleted, and similarly, a function that is inlined and the compiler can determine that it doesn't need an external reference can be deleted in its original form.

You can find out where a function is by `char *ptr = (char *)bar;`.

Edit: Note, by taking the address of a function, you may alter the inlining of the function, so don't expect this to be a good way to determine what the compiler does "under normal circumstances".

Comment: Thanks, I know how to find the function pointer, and that the compiler may omit / inline some functions, the question was regarding the order of the functions that actually exist in the compiled binary.

Comment: There is no rule about it in the language itself. Since compilers will have to keep a lot of data about the code in memory, it makes sense to output "in the order it came in", but there's absolutely no guarantee [just like there's no guarantee which order if-statements come, or that the else of one if is immediately after the if - I certainly have debugged Microsoft compiled code where the else is at the end of the function in some cases, despite the original if being the first statement in the function, and there being a lot of other if/else statement at the same "level" after that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to control this through compiler switches *alone*. You need a two-step process; illustrating this for ELF (the UN*X object file format) here, but it can be done analogous to this for Windows PE objects.

1. Instruct the compiler to generate separate / specific object file [ELF Sections](http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF#File_Structure) for functions whose code placement you must strictly control. This can either, in GCC, be done via [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) or via [command line switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274804/query-on-ffunction-section-fdata-sections-options-of-gcc).
   Depending on what type of placement you want to achieve, some of GCC's function attributes (`hot`, `cold`, ...) may already do what you need, but if not, and specific ordering / specific locations are absolutely necessary, then ...
2. Instruct the *linker* to order/rearrange/merge/position the input sections in specific way into the output.

The actual code / data placement happens at *link time* - the linker can control object code placement for "constitutent objects" - ELF sections of the source objects - within the resulting target "compound object", i.e. the resulting executable / library. This happens through *Linker Scripts*. The linker will place input sections at user-specified locations / in user-specified order into the output object if instructed to do so using a custom *Linker Script*. See the [GNU binutils (ld) manual](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/SECTIONS.html) about linker scripts.

As a result (reflecting where into the output the linker actually puts the various parts of the input) you can request a [Linker Mapfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755783/whats-the-use-of-map-files-the-linker-produces) to be generated; if you used a non-default / custom linker script to strictly control code placement, then you should instruct the linker to do that, so you can cross-check it did what you wanted. Otherwise, if you used the linker's default, the mapfile would tell you what's done without specific overrides - that may or may not be what you desire, but it at least is a way to check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such requirement. However, in your example, if bar() came after foo(), foo will consider bar() to be an yet undefined function that returns an integer.

Comment: Only if there is no forward declaration of `bar()`.